# duplicated entries in output after LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql, sqlite, left-join

I have a tab-separated two-column file "cluster-refSeq.csv" with many thousand entries like this:

```
chr10_100486611_100486680_+     NM_053314
chr10_102864904_102865004_-     NM_001013042
chr10_103280127_103280156_-     NM_001013042
```

Here, the entries in the "cluster" column are unique, but they can be linked to more than one refSeq.

I have another file "refSeq-symbol.csv" with many thousand entries like this:

```
NM_053314       Kcnj16
NM_053316       Ip6k1
NM_053317       Nr0b1
```

Here, the entries in the refSeq column are unique, but they can be linked to more than symbol.

The lines in each of these files are unique (there are no duplicated entries).

I want to join these two files such that cluster entries from the first file get linked to the symbol entries of the second file via the refseq entry. I want all possible, valid combinations. I think what I want is a LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Desired output should look like this:

```
chr10_100486611_100486680_+     NM_053314       Kcnj16
```

I tried to do that with sqlite:

```
create table alpha (cluster text, refseq text);
create table beta (refseq text, symbol text);
.separator "\t"
.import cluster-refSeq.csv alpha
.import refSeq-symbol.csv beta
select alpha.cluster, alpha.refseq, beta.symbol from alpha left outer join beta on alpha.refseq=beta.refseq;
```

This does generate the output I want (I think), but it does contain duplicated entries!

I.e. I get less triplets if I run the output through sort and uniq.

My question is: Am I actually doing what I think I'm doing with above sqlite code, and why do I get duplicated output rows? How can I fix my sqlite code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of duplicated rows use **DISTINCT**

BUT If you want to achive what you wrote in youre question then I think you need an **INNER JOIN** instead of **LEFT JOIN**

```
chr10_100486611_100486680_+     NM_053314
chr10_102864904_102865004_-     NM_001013042
chr10_103280127_103280156_-     NM_001013042


NM_053314       Kcnj16
NM_053316       Ip6k1
NM_053317       Nr0b1
```

With Left join the output would be:

```
chr10_100486611_100486680_+     NM_053314       Kcnj16
chr10_102864904_102865004_-     NM_001013042    NULL
chr10_103280127_103280156_-     NM_001013042    NULL
```

Instead of:

```
chr10_100486611_100486680_+     NM_053314       Kcnj16
```

Comment: Thanks! I was probably not clear enough, I think I do want a LEFT OUTER JOIN because I also want to keep entries from the first table/file which do not have an association in the second table/file.
Regarding DISTINCT that fixed it, but I still do not understand *why* I get these duplicated rows in the output.

Comment: Probably you have different rows with the same ID, like in your examlple the first two rows has the same NM_001013042 refSeq - may it is just a typo, but if you getting duplicates it means you have the duplicates in the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you add distinct to your query, that will eliminate duplicate rows

```
select distinct alpha.cluster,...
```